# Pip3 not working on OS X

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I recently redownloaded Python 3 to update it to the latest (3.5.2?) and I must have done something wrong.
Pip3 in my terminal is not responding anymore. When I type "pip3 install *some module*" it gives me back:

```
-bash pip3: command not found
```

I went into /usr/local/bin/ and saw that pip3 and pip3.5 are 0 bytes. I have rerun the install the python package in hopes of the installation fixing it.

My pip for 2.7 works correctly.

Edit: Checked and pip3 is right where it should (AKA /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin/pip3)

Edit2: Fixed it! first ran

```
python3 -m pip install *ModuleName*
```

and it ran correctly. 
it told me I needed to update my pip. So I did

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip
```

and after that pip3 was back to working.

Comment: How did you upgrade Python? What package (manager) did you use?

Comment: I used [this one](https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-352/). and downloaded the 64-bit/32-bit installer.

Answer (score 1):

This is only a guess, but `/usr/local/bin/pip3` etc. are probably only symbolic link to the real binary. You could run `ls -l /usr/local/bin/pip3` to see where the symbolic link points to.

Comment: it gave me a "no such file or directory".. Thanks for the try

Comment: What if you do `ls -l /usr/local/bin | grep pip`?

Comment: ok! Did it and it pointed me toward a few and one that looks like pip3

Answer (score 0):

You can try out the `ensurepip` module.

```
python -m ensurepip --upgrade
```